# how do I swap the values at index 2 and index 3 in a vector of type integer in C++?

Tags: c++

Problem: You have to swap the values between the 2nd and 3rd index of an array. The array is a vector array consisting of 10 elements.

assuming it is;

```
std::vector<int> arr1 = { 33,12,11,13,54,65,23,67,22,10 };
```

Final result:

before swapping:

```
33 12 11 13 54 65 23 67 22 10
```

after swapping:

```
33 12 13 11 54 65 23 67 22 10
```

Additional info:

1. Any concept of logic around the solution is allowed.
2. Apart from integer type the array should be able to take other datatypes.

Comment: `std::swap(arr[2], arr[3]);`

Comment: @essiendreamer28 It is unclear what is the problem.

Comment: I never knew the swap() function could work like that. I thought it was only able to swap between 2 arrays. Thank you!

Comment: @essiendreamer28 quick note for next time: `std::swap` can swap almost anything, because it use something called "template"

Comment: @justANewbie Thank you so much. I know about template.  template <typename T>

Comment: It is the same logic you would use if you had n barrels of wine and must swap the wine between barrel 2 and barrel 3. You need a third barrel. Perhaps you have an apprentice who has been trained to swap the contents of barrels with any fluid in them, so if you task them with swapping the wine they are able to do so, although they have only ever swapped milk and beer until now -- so you just tell them and they'll do it  (std::swap) ;-).

Comment: Metaphors aside: What's important to understand is that the operator[]() for vectors (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) returns a reference -- you can assign to it and change the vector element at that index. That may not be obvious.

Comment: Hints aside: Since you are new here let me kindly make you aware of a requirement we have here: You must show what you tried, and where it failed. Did you try to program anything? Did you create a vector? Could you assign values to it? Could you access those values? Then what piece was missing? If you are unable to write and compile a C++ program, or unable to use a vector, maybe you want to ask questions about that first.

Comment: @justANewbie: since the first index is `arr[0]`, shouldn't that be `std::swap(arr[1], arr[2])`?

Comment: Seriously, if you want any help you must show us what you tried: This is not a (pure) homework service. I have a nice demonstration program that I'm willing to share but you need to show me something first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 1**: Using `std::swap`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> vec= { 33,12,11,13,54,65,23,67,22,10};
   std::swap(vec[2], vec[3]);
   
   for(const int &elem: vec)
   {
       std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**: Manually using a `temp` variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//define a function template that takes the first argument as a vector of arbitrary type and second argument as first index to swap and the third argument as the second index to swap
template<typename T> 
void mySwap(std::vector<T>&vec, std::size_t indexOne, std::size_t indexTwo )
{
    
    T temp = vec.at(indexOne);
    vec.at(indexOne) = vec.at(indexTwo);
    vec.at(indexTwo) = temp;
}
int main()
{
    
   std::vector<int> vec= { 33,12,11,13,54,65,23,67,22,10};
   mySwap(vec, 2,3);
   
   for(const int &elem: vec)
   {
       std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

The second version is given just to illustrate how you can achieve the same effect as `std::swap`.

Comment: The question asks about swapping the 2th and the 3rd element in a `std::vector`

Comment: @justANewbie a `vector` is a dynamic array, so whether a `vector` or a C-style array is used, the logic is the same.

Comment: FYI, `std::swap()` for native types is in `<utility>` in C++11 and later, not `<algorithm>` anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know. Just trying to be a little bit nitpicky :-)

Comment: @justANewbie since this answer was already given in a comment, this should be as clear as possible and swap "between the 2nd and 3rd index".

Comment: For general `T`, one might wish to `std::move()` the values.  But I guess that's already fairly advanced for the level of the question...